# output html in conditional loops with Razor - raising error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to output HTML conditionally in Razor.

However, the HTML tags must 'balance'. This is fine for simple loops:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
}
```

But when I want to, say - output 3 `<div>` blocks, then a new row after every 3 `<div>` blocks it won't work - say using a Counter int like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Eating)
{
    if (Counter == 1)
    {
        <div class="row">
    }

    <div>
        Hello
    </div>

    Counter = Counter +1

    @if (Counter == 4)
    {
        </div>
    }
}
```

(I realise this is a slightly flawed / simplified example - but you get the idea)

The lower `</div>` returns the error "encountered end tag  with no matching start tag".

As a hackey solution I can just use `Response.Write("</div>")` for all these conditionals - but it seems to go against the spirit of Razor.

Is there a best practice way of doing this / a way I can do it without resorting to such hackey tactics?

I can find nothing on Google (I'm not really sure what to even search for).

thx.

Comment: This logic you have doesn't make much sense. There will always be an unclosed div for "row" or an unopen tag for "row"

Answer (score 1):

Use `@:` prefix when you are mixing normal html code inside code block.

This should work

```
@{
    var counter = 1;
    var totalCounter = Model.Eating.Count();
    var itemCounter = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in Model.Eating)
{
    itemCounter++;

    if (counter == 1)
    {
        @:<div class="row">
    }
    <div>Hello @item.Name</div>


    if (counter == 2 || ((itemCounter) ==totalCounter))
    {
        counter = 0;
        @:</div>
    }
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Or the below version which use the modulas operator and removes the counter variable declaration.

```
@{
    var numberOfRowsNeeded =4;
    var totalCounter = Model.Eating.Count();
    var itemCounter = 1;
}
@foreach (var item in Model.Eating)
{
    if (itemCounter % numberOfRowsNeeded==1)
    {
        @:<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid red; margin: 2px;">
    }
    <div>Helloss @item.Name</div>


    if ((itemCounter % numberOfRowsNeeded==0) || ((itemCounter) ==totalCounter))
    {
        @:</div>
    }
    itemCounter++;
}
```

Comment: thanks - the first option doesn't work at all, rows are output in every item loop - the counter conditional is ignored totally - it breaks the design. The second option doesn't really address that issue either. I'm looking for an alternative to response.write("</div>") etc - that will not throw up a razor error.

Comment: This will basically render a div for each item in the collection and group 4 of them in the outer div. See the working fiddle here. https://dotnetfiddle.net/unCNDv

Comment: thanks - for reference are you sure your first example works (the second does). I just find the modula a little unclear to read. thx.